# How can I keep docker container running?

Tags: docker, containers

I want to run multiple containers automatically and create something,

but some images, such as swarm, will automatically stop after run or start.

I already try like that

```bash
docker run -d swarm

docker run -d swarm /bin/bash tail -f /dev/null

docker run -itd swarm bash -c "while true; do sleep 1; done"
```

but 'docker ps' show nothing, and  I tried to build Dockerfile by typing:

```
FROM swarm
ENTRYPOINT ["echo"]
```

and The image does not run with error message :

```
docker: Error response from daemon: invalid header field value "oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused \"exec: \\\"echo\\\": executable file not found in $PATH\"\n".
```

I can't understand this error... How can I keep swarm container running..?

(Sorry,my English is not good))

Answer (score 13):

using **-d** is recommended because you can run your container with just one command and you don’t need to detach terminal of container by hitting **Ctrl + P + Q.**

However, there is a problem with -d option. Your container immediately stops **unless the commands are not running on foreground.**
Docker **requires your command to keep running in the foreground. Otherwise, it thinks that your applications stops and shutdown the container.**

The problem is that some application does not run in the foreground.

In this situation, you can add **tail -f /dev/null** to your command.
By doing this, even if your main command runs in the background, your container doesn’t stop because tail is keep running in the foreground.

**docker run -d swarm tail -f /dev/null**

**docker ps** shows container

Now you can attach your container by using **docker exec container_name command**

or

**docker run -d swarm command tail -f /dev/null**

Comment: As you tell me, I try this command but the container still can't keep running. If possible, could you confirm that when the swarm image run with that command, the container's show in the **docker ps**? I want to check whether my server is strange or not... and while waiting for an answer,  I did a simple test using Dockerfile and got an error message. I have updated the post, and I hope you can refer to it to solve this problem.Thank you for your continued interest in solving my problem

Answer (score 11):

First of all you don't want to mix the `-i` and `-d` switches. Either you would like to run the container in interactive or detached mode. In your case in detached mode:

```
docker run -d swarm /bin/bash tail -f /dev/null
```

There are also no need to allocate a tty using the `-t` flag, since this only needs to be done in interactive mode.

You should have a look at the [`Docker run reference`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/)

Comment: docker ps still show nothing..

I have to study more about the docker run. Thank you :)

Comment: @haeney - Did you get your container up and running?

Comment: Yes. Other containers such as nginx, Ubuntu, and redis run fine, but the swarm will terminate at the same time as it runs.

Answer (score 3):

Docker container does two type of task. One is to perform and exit & other is to run it in background.

To run docker container in background, there are few options.

1. Run using shell. `docker run -it <image> /bin/bash`
2. For continuously running container. `docker run -d -p 8080:8080 <image>`. Assuming image will expose port 8080 and in listening mode.

Answer (score 2):

It's fine to to a tail on /dev/null, but why not make it do something useful?

The following command will reap orphan processes, so no zombie (defunct) precesses are left floating around. Also some init.d / restart scripts doesn't allow this.

```bash
exec sh -c 'while true ;do wait ;done'
```

Comment: This is not a very nice command for waiting, as it won't exit cleanly when you stop it with `docker container stop`.

Comment: @lizuki What do you mean by "exit cleanly". I have not noted any adverse effects

Comment: The easiest way to see this is to run the container on foreground, that is without `-d`, and try to stop it with `ctrl + c`. You will see warnings about the kill signal.

Answer (score 0):

You are right **docker run -itd swarm** ( Without give argument for container( bash -c "while true; do sleep 1; done" ) )works fine .If you pass argument for docker run it will run the command and terminates the container.If you want to run the container permanently first start the container with **docker run -itd swarm** and check if the container runs or not by **docker ps** now the container runs , if you want to execute any command in container use **docker exec -itd container_name command**  Remember : Only use the command which not stop the container. *bash -c "while true; do sleep 1; done*  this command will stop the container ( Because this is complete command if we execute in normal terminal it execute and terminate , this type of command also terminates the container ).

I Hope this Helps..

Comment: my code step like that:
1. image run without command ( docker run -itd swarm)
2. check 'docker ps'
3. if the containner is not running, 
3-1 remove container and image run with command (docker run -itd swarm bash ...)

so, running an image without a command has no effect....

Answer (score 0):

Basically this is the method , but your docker image is swarm so it is different and i don't know about swarm docker image and i am not using that .But after i research about that . First i run the docker swarm image it shows.,

[image]

After that  i understand we run docker swarm image by using only five commands  in picture like create, list manage, join, help . if we run swarm image without command like **docker run -itd swarm**  it takes command as --help . Sorry, But i don't know what is the purpose of swarm image. For more usage check https://hub.docker.com/_/swarm/  .

The answer that i added **docker run -itd image tail -f /dev/null**  is not for swarm image , it is for docker images like ubuntu,fedora, centos.

Just read the usage of swarm image and why it is used .

After if you have any issue post your issue in https://github.com/docker/swarm-library-image/issues

Thank You...

Comment: I don't know the use of Swarm either.. Because my purpose is to get a lot of image information from the explore page and automatically pull and run it. But since Swarm is a special case, I will move on next step.. just it's kind of icky :(  Anyway, thank you ^^

Answer (score 0):

have a container running

```
docker run --rm -d --name=tmp ubuntu sleep infinity
```

example of requesting a command from the dorment container

```
docker exec tmp echo hello from container
```

notes:

- `--rm` removes the container if it is stopped
- `-d` runs the container in the background
- `--name=tmp` name the container so you control how to denote it
- `ubuntu` pushes a light image to exec your commands
- `sleep infinity` keeps the container dorment