# Docker container can't access sudo in build for react app

Tags: reactjs, docker, sudo

I'm trying to run a react app from a docker container (currently developing locally.) I get this error

```
Attaching to my-app_c
my-app_c  | 
my-app_c  | > my-app@0.1.0 start
my-app_c  | > sudo PORT=80 react-scripts start
my-app_c  | 
my-app_c  | sh: sudo: not found
my-app_c exited with code 127
```

I do have access to sudo. This [q/a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25845538/how-to-use-sudo-inside-a-docker-container) recommended running `docker exec -u root -t -i container_id /bin/bash` but this triggered another error: `Error response from daemon: Container bad3f69996f3814078d1ed94d3d261e3ffea2ab6a95f7151f576115fa6854f72 is not running`.

So it seems that I cannot give a docker container root permissions until it is already running and it cannot run until it has sudo access. How to I solve this chicken or the egg type problem?

Edit:

Showing Docker File and YAML file

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:17-alpine 
WORKDIR /my-app
COPY package.json . 
RUN npm install 
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  my-app: 
    build: ./my-app
    container_name: my-app_c
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
```

Comment: Could you please provide the Dockerfile that you use if you have it?

Comment: You don't show where the `sudo` actually is (in your `package.json` file, maybe?) but it works poorly in Docker and you almost never need it.  Possibly setting `CMD npx react-scripts start` could be a workaround?

Comment: Is that CMD [“npm”, “react-scripts”, “start”]? Or do I misunderstand you?

Comment: @DavidMaze could you clarify the CMD inputs?

Comment: So `CMD` just specifies the single command the container runs.  My best guess is that your `package.json` embeds the incorrect `sudo` command in its `"start"` script.  But if that just runs `react-scripts start` then you could put that command directly in `CMD` without the `npm` wrapper, using the [`npx`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/commands/npx) wrapper to find it in `node_modules/.bin`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `npm start` effectively runs a script, once the script is done, the container shuts down. You need to include a `CMD` or `RUN` that has a foreground process that doesn't stop (until you say so).

Also, the command you probably wanted is `docker run -it <image> /bin/bash` as given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56871919/6765734). The `exec` part only works to run a command on a running container, not to start one in a particular fashion.

Comment: Could you provide a CMD [x,…] example that illustrates your intent?

Comment: Generally speaking, that means an app that "runs." I Googled and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70755884/6765734). Also, [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/ops/running-docker-containers-indefinitely) never disappoints.

Comment: Thanks, also I tried `docker run -it my-app_c /bin/bash` but `my-app_c` could not be located. Is this what you meant by the image?

Comment: Have you built the image?

Comment: I ran ‘docker-compose up’ which I believe includes ‘docker build’ plus some additional steps

Comment: If you only used `docker-compose up`, it probably won't build automatically, you'd need to include the `--build` option. I've never used it that way as I like a bit of separation in the steps to create versus run. But if all you've done is make a `Dockerfile` and a `docker-compose.yaml` and haven't given a build instruction, that's the missing piece. Perhaps, include any outputs or errors in your question so we can get a better idea of your full process.